# parts of form going off to side when shown on smaller device

Tags: html, css

So I have an order form which works well but when I test it on smaller screens a part of it goes way off to the side, the rest is how it should be this one part is not for some reason.

This is the html code of the part that goes wrong:

```
<div class="contact" align="center">
<p>Please tell us who you are</p>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="550" id="table1">

<tr>
<td width="340" align="right">Name</font></td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" required size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right">Email</font> 
(Your confirmation will be sent here): </td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" required size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right">Phone number:</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="number" id="number" required size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right">Address:</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="address" id="address" required size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right">Town:</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="town" id="town" required size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right">Postcode:</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" required size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right">County:</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="county" id="county" required size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and not sure if it will help but this is the style for the border:

```
form {

    border-top-style: dotted;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  border-bottom-style: dotted;
  border-left-style: dotted;
}
```

For dealing with different screen sizes I added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have attached an image of what is happening to show what I mean:

[image]

I'm just not sure why this one bit is doing it and the rest of the form is fine? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Add your code to JSFiddle or a Codepen, and add the link here, please.

Comment: here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/jag73w6e/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 100%;` to the `table` element. Then adjust the width values you have given to each of the `td` elements. (I’d advise against a forced width for them, but it’s fine.)

It looks like this now—
[image: table]

Comment: and.. remove fixed `width` when you smaller them you can resize to ~400px width device

Comment: Agreed. Like I said— I’m not a fan of forced widths.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen unnecessary code

- like `<td>title</td><td width="10">&nbsp;</td>` Can be replace with `<td style="padding right: 10px">title</td>`
- blank last row `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>` Can be replace with table CSS `margin-bottom: 20px;`

**By the way**
you need to remove `<td width="100">` to `<td>`

```
table{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

tr>td:first-child{
  width:auto;/*340*/
  padding-right: 10px;
}
tr>td:last-child{
  width:auto;/*2pp*/
}
```

With my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/limitbrk/k1qyLv5h/) Now you can resize to... ~ 331px width (Can be resize less. If cut down `size` Input's attribute)

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot neater than what I had, works nicely as well